# No more space in root filesystem, how could I increase the size?

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, fedora, lvm

This is my filesystem :

```
 $ df -h -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root  9.8G  7.6G  1.7G  83% /
/dev/mapper/fedora-home   50G   27G   21G  57% /home
/dev/sda9               1022M  8.4M 1014M   1% /boot/efi
```

And as you can see the root filesystem is full.

I already tried to delete all the useless things but still I don't have enough space.

How could I increase it ? I have 60 giga left in my hard drive, is there any way I can move my root filesystem there ?

Comment: Can you show the result of `sudo pvscan`, please?

Comment: @mattdm   `PV /dev/sda10   VG fedora   lvm2 [141.56 GiB / 77.56 GiB free]
  Total: 1 [141.56 GiB] / in use: 1 [141.56 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]`

Comment: Erm, 1.7G free, where is the problem?

Comment: If this is your definition of "full" you should see my filesystem lol

Comment: @SimonRichter I had 1.9 giga when I removed all my /var/cache, but this directory filled very quickly and I have ~ 100 mo in average

Comment: I'd check what is filling it, and how to avoid that. If it's the package manager, can it be configured to clean its cache?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Good news! `pvscan` shows `PV /dev/sda10 VG fedora lvm2 [141.56 GiB / 77.56 GiB free]` — so you should be able to add up to 77.56GiB to any of your filesystems. I'd suggest adding it in smaller blocks (like 10GiB), so you have a reserve to put into `/home` if you decide you need growth there later.

This is a relatively well-tested and generally safe operation, but all root-level volume and filesystem operations have some risk — make sure you have a functioning backup first. Then....

You can extend your `root` logical volume to use the free space with `lvextend`, like this:

```
sudo lvextend --size +10G --resizefs /dev/fedora/root
```

(Or `-L` and `-r` instead of `--size` and `--resizefs`, if you prefer short options.)

Comment: While it's always a good idea to have backups. I would consider this to be pretty low risk since no existing data is moved and the filesystem is (presumablly) native linux, not reverse engineered.

Comment: `141.56 GiB / 77.56 GiB free` reads like X out of Y free. So at first I thought it was a joke :P

Comment: @Insane Yeah, that's not the best formatting. You can get the same information formatted in different ways from `pvs` or `pvdisplay`, if you prefer.

Answer (score 10):

More general answer for LVM:

Firstly - make sure you have additional unpartitioned storage. Then:

1. Use `fdisk` to create new partition (safer than expanding existing one)
2. Use `pvcreate` to create physical LVM volume:

   ```
   pvcreate /dev/sdxx
   ```
3. Use `vgextend` to extend existing LVM group using new physical volume:

   ```
   vgextend groupname /dev/sdxx
   ```

   You can get group names with `vgdisplay`
4. Use `lvextend` on lvm mapper to expand lvm volume:

   ```
   lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/xxx
   ```
5. Grow the filesystem:

   ```
   xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/xxx
   ```

   Or

   ```
   resize2fs /dev/mapper/xxx
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The / filesystem may be a particular challenge, as that needs to be supported by the boot loader.

This answer doesn't specify how to accomplish the requested task, but does provide a workaround.

Another option: find a sub-directory (e.g., /big/) which has lots of data.  Then copy that data onto your 60GB of space, mv the directory with lots of space (e.g., mv /big /bigback), and mount your 60GB (or a portion of it) onto /big.  After confirming everything works as expected, rm /bigback to re-gain space on /

Comment: If you do this, immediately after, do `touch /.autorelabel; reboot` to make sure the moved files have the right SELinux labels.

Comment: This  is a valid and useful solution (not requiring much knowledge) when we fly without LVM. With it, the change is even less painful.

Comment: There is no reason in principle that / needs to be supported by the bootloader, but in this case it is true because there is no separate /boot. When monkeying with LVM, always make /boot real.

Answer (score -1):

Another option, before you attempt anything more drastic, is to use [BleachBit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BleachBit) to remove temporary and other unneeded files.

From wikipedia:

> BleachBit is a free and open-source disk space cleaner, privacy
>   manager, and computer system optimizer.

It should be in the package manager, so this should do it.

```
sudo yum install bleachbit
```

Or [download from their page](http://www.bleachbit.org/download/linux).